# Apache Zookeeper server not starting on Windows

Tags: java, cloud, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

I installed a stable version of Apache Zookeeper-3.4.12, made the changes in the conf folder by changing the name of the configuration file to 'zoo.cfg'. Updated the path of the Datadir from Temp to Users. Even after doing this, when I try the 'zkServer.cmd' command I get the following error-:
Please help me out, I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the issue by editing the zkServer.cmd file and removing the %*, at the end of the CALL line beside "%ZOOCFG". Because of this error, I was unable to properly run my zookeeper server, but now I finally can :)